# How can I use TailwindCSS to dynamically update an element's color value?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, tailwind-css

I have a website where I want a user to be able to update a div's color dynamically using TailwindCSS. However, when I add a class, it seems that Tailwind does not reflect the change.

Please note that the example provided, although it does work here, does not reflect the *true behavior* of a properly installed Tailwind dependency. This is because Tailwind's (as installed per instructions) classes are defined at compile time, while the cdn is built at runtime. Basically, the CDN is updated for every change in the DOM, while Tailwinds "prod" is created based on a simple analysis of the html/js/css files.

I've elected to include the CDN version. This is included here because it contains the desired behaviour for my application, and is the only version I can include. If you'd like to reproduce the problem behavior, simply copy the code into a normal [Tailwinds installation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) project and edit out the  `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>` line.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const colorValue = document.querySelector("input").value;
  const div = document.querySelector("div");
  div.classList.remove("bg-[#864b4b]");
  div.classList.add(`bg-[${colorValue}]`);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Example issue</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="ml-4 h-96">
  <label for="color-pick" class="block font-extrabold text-slate-800">Pick a color</label
    >
    <input type="color" class="mb-4" name="color-pick" id="color-pick" />
    <button
      type="button"
      class="block text-slate-100 font-bold bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2"
    >
      Change div to chosen color
    </button>
    <div class="w-20 h-20 bg-[#864b4b]"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my opinion, the only this can be done is by editing the style of the element by using the `style` attribute. However, if there is a Tailwinds way to do it, it would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: You need to refer this docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the `style` attribute:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const colorValue = document.querySelector("input").value;
  const div = document.querySelector("div");
  div.classList.remove("bg-[#864b4b]");
  div.style.backgroundColor = colorValue;
});
```

Comment: I guess this is the answer. I get why Tailwind doesn't that though